# Best way to do many try-except blocks within Python class assignments?

Tags: python, json

I have a class which is pulling JSON data with keys, but the problem is that per instance of this class, the JSON data may not have keys for everything I am trying to grab.  Currently, my class is set up like this:

```
class Show():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.status = self.data['status']
        self.rating = self.data['rating']
        self.genres = self.data['genres']
        self.weight = self.data['weight']
        self.updated = self.data['updated']
        self.name = self.data['name']
        self.language = self.data['language']
        self.schedule = self.data['schedule']
        self.url = self.data['url']
        self.image = self.data['image']
```

And so on, there are more parameters than that.  I'm trying to avoid the messiness of having a try-except block for EACH AND EVERY one of those (27) lines.  Is there a better way?  Ultimately, I want a parameter to be assigned `None` if the JSON key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to set a default value to the attribute if it's not in the `data` dictionary, use `data.get('key')` rather than `data['key']`. The `get` method will return `None` if the key does not exist, rather than raising a `KeyError` exception. If you want a different default value than `None`, you can pass a second argument to `get` and that is what will be returned.

So, your code could become:

```
class Show():
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.status = self.data.get('status')
    self.rating = self.data.get('rating')
    self.genres = self.data.get('genres')
    self.weight = self.data.get('weight')
    self.updated = self.data.get('updated')
    self.name = self.data.get('name')
    self.language = self.data.get('language')
    self.schedule = self.data.get('schedule')
    self.url = self.data.get('url')
    self.image = self.data.get('image')
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  What is the syntax for nested keys?  Some of the parameters are as many as 3 keys deep eg. ['network']['country']['timezone']

Comment: Are the intermediate dictionaries guaranteed to exist? If so, you can just use `get` at the last level (where the item might not exist). If the dictionaries on the way might not exist, you'll have to use `get` at every level, with an empty dictionary as the default: `data.get("network", {}).get("country", {}).get("timezone")`

Comment: Perfect!  The intermediate dicts are not guaranteed to exist, so I'll use .get for each level.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm, it looks like this isn't actually working with nested dicts.  I'm getting:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`
from the code
 `self.data.get("network", {}).get("country", {}).get("timezone", {})`

Comment: Looks like it is working only if the first key does exist and is not None.  In the case of this error, there is a "network" key but its value in the JSON is None.  Is there a way to handle this without try-except?

Comment: If your dictionary from JSON already has `None` values in it, than `get` won't let you pick a different default. You'll have to use `try`/`except` or other conditional logic (e.g. `if data["network"] is None`...).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), which provides a default value instead of raising an exception for missing keys.

For example, you can change this:

```
self.status = self.data['status']
```

into this:

```
self.status = self.data.get('status')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your code to something like:

```
class Show():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.__dict__.update(data)

data = {'status': True, 'ratings': [1,2,3], 'foo': "blahblah"}

aShow = Show(data)
"""
>>> aShow.status
True
>>> aShow.ratings
[1,2,3]
>>> aShow.something_not_in_dict
AttributeError: Show instance has no attribute 'something_not_in_dict'
"""
```

Which does exactly the same, and trying to access something from your `Show` instance that isn't a key in your `data` dictionary would raise an `AttributeError`

Comment: Cool!  Never knew about __dict__.update().  Unfortunately I'm not sure this works well for the nested values I want to expose, I would sill need to do an explicit assignment for things like data['network']['country']['name'].  Maybe I need to come to terms with that and let the user dig deeper when they need to instead of trying to make EVERYTHING an object attribute.